# Minimize the chances of duplicate question in SO sites while Migration

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation, flags, migrated-questions

I do not know the exact procedure behind the migration process, but as far as i know it needs moderator attention and have to raise a flag to migrate.

Are SO sites smart enough to suggest the target sites while asking a question, so that a user post the question in the related sites?

This will definitely help to reduce the possibility of duplicate questions when they are migrated to the target SO sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is plain impossible to detect this automatically. This is the reason we have moderators and the flagging and voting mechanisms.